# Extract time from a mixture of date & time Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to extract Time from A column that is a mix of date and Time.

- I can get the right output but I have to go through a series of first Splitting the text using the "T" delimiter.
- Then again Split the resultant using the "+" delimiter which gives me the Time only.
  Then count and remove the last 3 characters which takes up multiple columns.

Need a formula that does this in a single column if possible.

Some of what I tried already:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(RIGHT(K2:K,LEN(K2:K)-(FIND(":",K2:K)+1)))
```

[image]

Link to spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W9XZ2adqa9mFqvu-CrJsQhrKpH59VlmzpWwTvolNmRQ/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows strange expected results in cells B2 and B3. In both cases, minutes are extracted, but displayed in different digits. Specify, please.
This formula for B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"T\d{2}:(.*)\+"))
```

and this one is for B3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"T(.*):\d{2}\+"))
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Updated question.